# Script for Inserting a Timestamp as Header when data is copied to new adjacent column?

Tags: google-sheets

I currently run script to daily copy data from a single column and paste to the adjacent column, what I am now trying to add is to place a timestamp as the header of this data when the data is copied. This script runs every day at a certain time and keeps pasting data to the adjacent column.

Below is the script I am currently running. Can anyone assist?

```
function readfleetnum()  {
    var sheetFrom = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet5");
    var sheetTo = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet5");
    var valuesToCopy = sheetFrom.getRange(2, 2, sheetFrom.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
    sheetTo.getRange(2,sheetTo.getLastColumn()+1,valuesToCopy.length,1).setValues(valuesToCopy);
}
```

Comment: Hi Dan, a simple way would be to get the range of the header (which will be sheet.getLastColumn() after adding data to new col)... use ` var header - new Date();` and set the cell to that? Note that you don't need sheetFrom and sheetTo, as they are the same reference... just `sheet` will do.

Answer (score 0):

```
function readfleetnum()  {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet5");

  var vals = sheet.getRange(2, 2, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();

  sheet.getRange(2,sheet.getLastColumn()+1,valuesToCopy.length,1)
    .setValues(vals);

  var header = new Date();

  sheet.getRange(1,sheet.getLastColumn(),1,1)
    .setValue(header);

}
```

Note the diff between setValues and setValue.